# Java FlowLayout in GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, date, layout, user-interface

I would like to move the date to the top left corner but with the flowlayout row the panel elements goes to right without to the center.
How can I modify the gridlayout to move those to the right place or should I fill the flowlayout with unvisible element?

Thanks.

```
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;
    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JTextArea;


    public class abba extends JPanel{

        Date dátum = new Date();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        JLabel dát = new JLabel("Dátum: ");
        JTextArea év = new JTextArea("");
        JTextArea hónap = new JTextArea("");
        JTextArea nap = new JTextArea("");


        public class Date1 extends JPanel{

            public Date1(){

                setLayout(new FlowLayout(4));

                cal.setTime(dátum);
                int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
                int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                év.setText(year+"");
                év.setColumns(4);
                hónap.setText(month+"");
                hónap.setColumns(2);
                nap.setText(day+"");
                nap.setColumns(2);

                add(dát);
                add(év);
                add(hónap);
                add(nap);
            }
        }




        public static void main(String args[]) {
            abba a = new abba();
            JFrame aa = new JFrame("Frame");
            aa.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            aa.setSize(300, 300);
            aa.add(a);
            aa.setVisible(true);
        }

        public abba(){
            setLayout(new GridLayout(10,1));
            add(new Date1());
        //...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Rather use Box layout inside your grid layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
setLayout(new FlowLayout(4));
```

with

```
setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
```

Use of the `FlowLayout` constant field argument rather than magic numbers. (4 = `FlowLayout.TRAILING`)